# How to pass data in HTML Select Option Tag?

Tags: php, slim

How can I get all the data from a single column in my database.

I'm creating a bank deposit select option, that when the select his/her desired bank, he/she will receive an email with appropriate value.

Assuming this is my database

```
bank_id   bank_name   account_name   account_number   account_type
1         bank_no1    bank_no1_name  111111111        savings
2         bank_no2    bank_no2_name  222222222        check
```

What I want, is when I select `bank_no1` or `bank_no2` all of it's data will be shown to email ..

```
<select name="bank_id" id="bank_id">
   <option value="<?php echo bank_no1?>"><?php echo bank_no1?></option>
   <option value="<?php echo bank_no2?>"><?php echo bank_no2?></option>
</select>
```

Because right now in my email, i'm receiving only the `bank_name`. How can I make it possible??

By the way, I'm using `slim`, that code is just an example just to make a simple explanation

Comment: Why not store the `bank_id` in the `select` then when you are about to send an email, query a `SELECT` using the `bank_id` chosen

Comment: @Swellar , ok sir i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

To get all the data related to a column based on the bank account number you need to craft a database `Select` statement passing in the bank account number as a variable. Then storing the statement as a variable, and passing it to your database, which will return any matches. Such as:

```
<form action="bank_loader.php" method="post"> 
<select name="bank_name">
  <option value="1">bank_no1</option>
  <option value="2">bank_no2</option>
  <option value="3">bank_no3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
// make a connection to your MySQLi server using credentials
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// get the form data from the bank_name select
$bank_noX = $_POST["bank_name"];
// construct an SQL string passing in the bank number
$sql = "Select * FROM Accounts WHERE bank_name IS " . $bank_noX;
// query the SQL database using our established connection and store in $result
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Then your results for that bank number are in `$result` and you can parse the data with `$result->fetch_assoc()`. For example,

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf("Bank ID: " . $row['bank_id'] . ", Hello " . $row['account_name']);
}
```

This is assuming that you have an MySQLi database, and a connection to it.